# How to access service from Website from Chrome Extension using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

When I call on my developer console window.services in Google Chrome, it will present all services the website is using to me.
When I try to execute the exact same command from my Chrome extension in the Main World, the "services" property isn't present.
I need information from the services for my further development.
[This is the command I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYQOX.jpg)

I tried to call the property, and it didn't work, as mentioned above. I also tried to obtain the URL's, which are called by the services, but I don't know how.
Furthermore, I tried content scripts to access the property. Content scripts will be executed, as soon as the site starts loading.
The problem is, that the services with results are loaded on a later point, so I can't use them here.
Trying to embed scripts directly in the DOM leaded to security issues.
The following image shows, that the property "services" does not exist.
[image: Here you can see the property "services" is missing]